# Possible Energies after Elastic Collision

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws

I have a Gold Atom that hits a Magnesium Atom. The Gold atom is 1.7 MeV. How can I find the range of energies that the Mg could have? This would obviously depend on the angle of impact, but curios what this range could be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anywhere from zero to the energy that can be transferred in a head-on collision, which can be determined through simple mechanics. To get the appropriate full distribution, use the Rutherford formula.

Comment: You set up the conservation equations with the scattering angle represented by a letter (like, say, $\Theta$), solve the system as far as possible and figure out the bounds of the set of solutions?

Comment: In the laboratory frame, think of a billiard ball game . One ball at rest at the table, one coming in with energy for a hit. If it is grazing angle practically zero, if head on all the energy of motion can be transferred. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RVTP7LQE3k